# Correctly packaging CSS files for deployment to Azure CDN as part of Azure DevOps extension

Tags: css, azure-devops, http-status-code-404, azure-devops-extensions

I'm developing an Azure DevOps extension, which displays the a summary of work items for the current Sprint for printing.

I am failing to get static CSS files to publish correctly.

I have the following configured in the manifest.json in the files section:

```
    {
        "path": "css/print.css",
        "contentType": "text/css",
        "addressable": true
    },
    {
        "path": "css/screen.css",
        "contentType": "text/css",
        "addressable": true
    },
```

The structure of the project is:

```
css/screen.css
css/print.css
board-cards.html
vss-extension.json
```

Reading this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/static-content indicates that the static content *should* be published to: https://publisher.gallery.vsassets.io.

When debugging - the following two 404's appear in the network log:

https://publisher.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/css/print.css
https://publisher.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/css/screen.css

(*I've changed my publisher account name to the generic "publisher" string for ease*)

I've opened the .vsix in 7zip, and the folder and css files are in the package.  After many hours of Googling and hunting through stackoverflow, I'm unable to find a solution.

I tried changing the entry in "files" to be simply:

```
{
   "path": "css",
   "addressable": true
}
```

However this had no effect.

Is anyone able to advise me on what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Through further debugging I've found that the files do exist under a URL specific the the version published - e.g. https://publisher.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/publisher/board-cards/1.0.64/1545996658773/css/screen.css

I don't know how I'm supposed to package these files up so that the CSS is referenced relatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through further debugging I've found that the files do exist under a URL specific the the version published.

e.g. https://publisher.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/publisher/board-cards/1.0.64/1545996658773/css/screen.css

And then I checked the mark-up, and I realised I'd made an absolute reference to the CSS files. E.g.

```
/css/screen.css
```

By removing the first slash - this made the reference to the CSS file relative, which solved the problem.

HTML 101.